# error while building gRPC service in .net 6

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-6.0

I try to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-grpc-service-1) tutorial, but I can't run the gRPC service. Here is the output:
[image: console output]

Raw output text:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: GrpcGreeter, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Build started 12.03.2023 03:04:46.
1>Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
1>  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>Target _Protobuf_CoreCompile:
1>  C:\Users\Paweł\.nuget\packages\grpc.tools\2.40.0\build\_protobuf\Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB6006: "C:\Users\Paweł\.nuget\packages\grpc.tools\2.40.0\tools\windows_x64\protoc.exe" exited with code -1073741819.
1>Done building target "_Protobuf_CoreCompile" in project "GrpcGreeter.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Done building project "GrpcGreeter.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>C:\Users\Paweł\.nuget\packages\grpc.tools\2.40.0\build\_protobuf\Google.Protobuf.Tools.targets(280,5): error MSB6006: "C:\Users\Paweł\.nuget\packages\grpc.tools\2.40.0\tools\windows_x64\protoc.exe" exited with code -1073741819.
1>    0 Warning(s)
1>    1 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.70
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 3:04 AM and took 02,212 seconds ==========
```

I was trying with .net 5, 6 and 7, but unfortunately with no success.
I suspect, the problem might be with non-ascii characters in path to nuget packages, but I'm not sure. Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT:
Here's my proto file. I haven't changed anything here, it was already generated by vs.

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcGreeter";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

and GreeterService.cs (also auto-generated):

```
using Grpc.Core;
using GrpcGreeter;

namespace GrpcGreeter.Services
{
    public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
        public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
            {
                Message = "Hello " + request.Name
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing a clean build.  c# does not recognize when a library gets updated and will not automatically recompile all the code.  You have intermediate obj files that are new than the c# source so you code is skipping compiling with new library.  Clean Build will force all the code to recompile.

Comment: @jdweng That's weird, but it somehow still remains skipped. I tried clean + build and rebuild but I still receive: `Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.`

Comment: The dependencies in the csproj file may be wrong.   Often people manually put files into the bin folder instead of adding objects to the project.  Then these files do not automatically get updated.  The csproj file is text and can be opened with any text editor.  I would compare the files in the bin folder with the csproj to see what is happening.  Check the dates of the files in the bin to see if any are old and not getting compiled.

Comment: If protoc returns an error code, you should check for its output. Probably your proto definitions are incorrect, but you haven't posted them.

Comment: @jdweng I've got some entries in csproj but bin directory is empty (well, it contains debug dir but it's empty as well). If you are interested, here's the content of csproj file: https://pastebin.com/E7YLkhLR

Comment: @Ray I've just added them to my post.

Comment: Well if it's the default .proto, it wouldn't be the issue. Your error code is 0xC0000005, which is an access violation. Seems to be an internal bug to protoc, and I have no idea why it's caused.

Comment: Try following : https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet#to-develop-grpc-for-aspnet-core

Comment: @jdweng I followed these commands, but while building the same problem occured :(

Comment: Then libraries aren't installed properly look at previous link at sections above.  Your csproj is removing nuget and then including nuget.  That doesn't look right.

Comment: What's worth to mention - I've got a yellow triagnle next to grpc.AspNetCore package icon. As I investigated, it means that some packages are not physically on my machine and I tried to reload project, restore packages, update this package, but all these methods failed.

Comment: Here's how it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/j04WAI7

Comment: Posting the contents of your csproj file may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Verify greet.proto properties...

- Build Action - Protobuf compiler
- gRPC Stub Classes - Server only

[image]

If you are not able to see properties, you can check in project file as well.

[image]

Once you verify this, re-build project.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I already know what was wrong. It turned out, that it indeed was a problem with non-ascii character (ł) in my path to packages. The solution was to move .nuget directory from my default location to some other directory (with ascii-only characters in path). Then you need to add nuget.config file to solution with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="[rel_path]\.nuget\packages" />
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="[rel_path]\.nuget\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Where [rel_path] is relative path to your moved .nuget directory. Of course relative to current location of nuget.config file. Thank you for your help though.